# Elif unexpected indentation when trying to print out single line with total count

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, printing

I have created a very simple function that counts the number of occurrences in a list, however, I cannot get one single line to print out the total number of occurrences because the elif part of my if statement creates an unexpected indentation error in my code. I'm using the elif part to check whether the code entered is part of the list or not.

So for example, instead of getting:

```
2 entries(s) for uk found
```

I get:

```
1 entries(s) for uk found
2 entries(s) for uk found
```

Can anyone please help me out with a suggestion on how to correct this? Thanks a lot !

PS: This is just my third week coding, please take it easy on me guys.

```
def myList(list):
    countOccurrence = 0    
    for code in list:
        if code == countryCode:
            countOccurrence += 1              
            print str(countOccurrence) + ' entrie(s) for ' + str(countryCode) + ' found'            
        elif countryCode not in list:
            print 'Invalid Country Code'
            break      

list = ['ec','us','uk','ur','br','ur', 'ur', 'uk']

countryCode = raw_input('Please provide country code > ')
myList(list)
```

Comment: `list` in an inbuilt function. Use a different variable name.

Comment: Thanks. Overlooked that one.

Comment: Move `print` after `for`loop, then you'll get your single line. And I haven't understood what's the problem with unexpected indentation.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried your suggestion and it works when a valid code is entered, however, when an invalid country code is entered the Invalid Country Code message is printed and right after the 0 entrie(s) for wrongcodehere message kicks in too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print` line is also inside your `for` loop. Consider instead:

```
def my_func(lst):
    count = 0
    if code not in countryCode:
        print "Invalid Country Code"
        return
    for code in lst:
        if code == countryCode:
            count += 1
    print count
```

Or even better:

```
def my_func(lst):
    count = lst.count(countryCode)
    # list.count(x) returns how many times x appears in list
    if count == 0:
        print "Invalid Country Code"
    else:
        print count
```

Comment: Thanks so much Adam, the second suggestion works like a charm.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion as well, but keep getting 0 count for some reason.